# Get next Sunday after a given date (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is there any built-in function to get next Sunday (next Monday, Tuesday, etc.) from a given date using bash shell script?
For example, what is the first Sunday after 1-Sep-2014? I expect 7-Sep-2014.

I have searched the answer in google, but only found this function :

```
date "+%Y%m%d" -d Sun
```

which is to get next Sunday after today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear `date` can't do it directly. But you can use brace expansion to get the dates for all the following 7 days and select Sunday from them:

```
echo '1-Sep-2014\ +'{1..7}'\ days' | LC_ALL=C xargs -n1 date -d | grep Sun
```

The `LC_ALL=C` makes the output of `date` independent on the current locale.

Comment: This works great. Note that if you are on a unix system, make sure you have GNU date. A homebrew solution of `brew install coreutils` will result in GNU date called in by `gdate`.

Comment: Great answer, @choroba :). By the way, is it possible to parameterize the date (1-Sep-2014) as well as the day (Sun). I tried this code, but return error : `echo '$myDate\ +'{1..7}'\ days' | xargs -n1 date -d | grep $myDay`

Comment: I placed the first quote at wrong position. It works now : `echo ${myDate}'\ +'{1..7}'\ days' | xargs -n1 date -d | grep $myDay`

Comment: It is possible to do this directly with `date`, but you need two invocations: one to print out some information and the second to calculate and format the output date. See [my answer here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432999/313192).

Comment: Love this solution. I've noticed it is locale dependent ("Sun"). The following will make it not dependent on the locale:
`echo $START+{0..6}days | xargs -n1 date '+%w%Y%m%d' -d | grep -oP '^0\K.*$'`

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks for the comment. I made it locale independent in a different way, but yours is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
w=$(date -d"$1" +%w)
diff=$(( (7-$w)%7 ))
date -d"+$diff day $1" +%F
```

saved as `sun.sh` then:

```
kent$  ./sun.sh 01-Sep-2014
2014-09-07

kent$  ./sun.sh 31-Aug-2014
2014-08-31

kent$  ./sun.sh 3-Sep-2014   
2014-09-07

kent$  ./sun.sh 23-Sep-2014
2014-09-28
```

Note that, argument validation was not done, I just showed how to calculate the date.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make `date` do all the math without using shell code for math functions or to iterate though output looking for answers. The `date` function can do basic math like "x + 1 days" or "x - 1 month + 2 days".
It can also output formatted strings with arbitrary values.

The trick here is to use one date invocation to output the string used to calculate your final answer. We'll input your input date and ask for what day of the week that is, but at the same time output some math to subtract that number of days. By adding 7 days first we'll end up an the next week, then by subtracting the day-of-the-week number from that we'll have the next Sunday:

```
INPUTDATE="20140901"
date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$(date +"%Y%m%d + 7 days - %w days" -d "$INPUTDATE")"
```

This will spit out your expected answer: 20140907. Of course you can change the output format using the format string on the outer date invocation.